# binding radio buttons to ng-model with angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, radio-button, angularjs-ng-model

So this is the relevant part of my html-code. i tried binding the "formFriendsAll" scope to the ng-model.

```
<form ng-submit="submitForm()" >
   <div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="form-group"> 
     <label>Which Persons to show?</label>
      <div class="radio">
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="FriendsAll" ng-model="formFriendsAll" value="Friends" >
          Friends
        </label>
        </div>
         <div class="radio">
          <label>
           <input type="radio" name="FriendsAll" ng-model="formFriendsAll" value="Alle">
           All
          </label>
          </div>
          <div>currently selected: {{formFriendsAll}}</div>
         </div>           
        </div><td><input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Los!"/></td> </form>
```

This is the relevant js-code:

```
 var challenge =  angular.module('challengeApp', []) 
    challenge.controller('challengeController', function($scope) {   

      $scope.submitForm = function () {
      alert($scope.formFriendsAll);   
};  

    $scope.formFriendsAll = 'Friends';

});
```

I used the alert to test the change of value when i hit the submit button but i tried various methods like ng-changed, ng-click, ng-value. but nothing helped me solve the issue that my alert and "currently selected" stays on "Friends"

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

ok guys. seems like the AdminLTE.css i used in my head for the design of the radio buttons blocked the angular somehow